# SetInformationJobObject failes with ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to set priority class for child process, but SetInformationJobObject function failes with 1314 error code. So how to solve this?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION limits;
    limits.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PRIORITY_CLASS;
    limits.PriorityClass = HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS;

    HANDLE Job = CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL);

    SetInformationJobObject(Job, JobObjectBasicLimitInformation, &limits, sizeof(limits));
    cout << GetLastError() << endl;
    AssignProcessToJobObject(Job, GetCurrentProcess());

    STARTUPINFO cif;
    ZeroMemory(&cif, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    cif.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    CreateProcess("sp.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &cif, &pi);

    cout << "Child process priority = " << GetPriorityClass(pi.hProcess);

    CloseHandle(Job);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

GetPriorityClass must return 128, but returns 32.

Comment: you need have `SE_INC_BASE_PRIORITY_NAME` privilege. error code say that you have not this privilege or not enable it

Comment: I set SE_INC_BASE_PRIORITY_NAME privilege for current process and it worked.

Comment: I just did not see the clarification about the necessary privilege on msdn. GetPriorityClass returns 128, so problem solved, thanks!